# Printing CSV value patterns in Python

Tags: python, csv, pattern-matching

I have already loaded my CSV file and saved it to a list.

When performing actions such as calculating empty fields, I have created a method like:

```
def calc_empty(self):
    """Calculates the total number of empty fields"""
    empty = 0
    for x in range(0, self.tot_col):
        for y in range(1, self.tot_rows + 1):
            if self.file_list[y][x] == '':
                empty += 1
```

`tot.col` and `tot.rows` have been initialised when the class file is called.

I would like to now be able to find patterns within each column like so:

```
System 1: 123-45-6789 
Pattern: 9(3)-(2)-(4)

System 1: 12-3456789  
Pattern: 9(2)-(7)

System 2: 123456789
Pattern: 9(9)
```

However, only unique patterns should be printed in each column.

How would I go about doing this, I assume there's a count at some point?

Edit:

System 1 & System 2 represent column headers. I have the column headers also saved in a list created when the CSV file is initially read.

The entire CSV file has been saved in a list called: `file_list`
and the column headers have been set to: `headers = file_list[0]`

Comment: So you want to find how many characters are in a `string` not including the `-` characters? And also the sub-count between each `-`, correct?

Comment: Correct, however there could be a space, _ or - between each.

Comment: What does "System 1" in your example refer to? How do you define "pattern"? I think you'll need to include a lot more details of what it is you're trying to do to get a reasonable answer.

Comment: @LaurenceGonsalves Please see updated post.
Not quite sure how to define pattern other than say, a sequence, an arrangement of how the characters within a string are laid out, just as Cyber has noticed in the post.

Comment: Is your question about how to compute a "pattern" for a given string, or is it about how to find the unique ones in each column?

Comment: @LaurenceGonsalves it is about finding unique patterns within a column.